# ClearRange automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to clear a specific range of my Google Sheet twice a day by triggering this function.
My script is as follows:

```
function clearRange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('test');
  sheet.getRange('inventaire!B3:E8').clearContent();
}
```

But I get

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getSheetByName" of null. (line 3, file "Code")

I don't know why I receive this error.

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: If this script is not bound to a spreadsheet, then the call to `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()` will return `null`. This is stated in documentation. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you pass as parameter the name of the sheet where belongs the range in this case `inventaire` not `test`, by the way it appears your app is not linked to a spreadsheet as `getActive`returns `null`. Try to make sure your script is linked to your spreadsheet try also the `getActiveSpreadsheet()` method then write.

```
function clearRange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('inventaire');
  sheet.getRange('B3:E8').clearContent();
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, of course. test is the name of the document, but inventaire is the name of the sheet (and not the tab). It works. Thanks

Comment: can you validate as answered please?

Comment: Note that this doesn't resolve the OP's error. OP's error clearly states that the object on which `getSheetByName` is called is `null` - it is not an instance of a `Spreadsheet`.

Comment: because test is not a sheet it is the spreadsheet, so this solves the problem. There Imagine test was the sheet there would be no logic in calling the range of another sheet in the `test`sheet object. So you clarify the logic and errors from user seems more clear

Comment: if OP breaks up the code to this: `var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("some name");`, the error OP is getting indicates that the value of `spreadsheet` will be `null`. It doesn't matter what the name of the sheet being requested is, because *the spreadsheet being acted on does not exist*

Comment: yes I've putted that on the post. `by the way it appears test sheet doesn't exist`

Comment: What @tehhowch says is that the error is in this part of the line: `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()`. Although what you pointed out is a problem. It will produce this error: `TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 3, file "code")` rather than the one mentioned by OP. Try and see. It is probable that OP quoted it wrong too.

Comment: @I'-'I  ho  your right I've unerstood I've just edited my post